# FMX Loading image from resources onto a listview object causes access violation

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a TListview with a Dynamic Appearance. I added a image object and now I'm trying to load an image from the resources onto this imageobject but I keep getting a access violation.

My Code:

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnAddPlayerClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ListItem: TListViewItem;
  imgBanned: TListItemImage;
  InStream: TResourceStream;
begin
  InStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'banned', RT_RCDATA);
  lvPlayers.BeginUpdate;
  try
    ListItem := lvPlayers.Items.Add;
    imgBanned := ListItem.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemImage>('imgBanned');
    imgBanned.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(InStream);
  finally
    lvPlayers.EndUpdate;
    InStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

EDIT:
After Debugging I get the following but I have no idea what it means. I see that it has something to do with GetFieldAddress but I'm unsure as to what this is

[image]
[image]

Comment: You miss try/finally for the BeginUpdate/EndUpdate. As for the AV. Do some debugging. This is the most important skill you need to bone. Step through and inspect all the variables. Is one of them nil. And when asking a question about an error always include the error message. You might not yet understand the hex in the AV message, but we can teach you what it means.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks. I have updated the Question with the debugging info and I have fixed the beginupdate and endupdate

Comment: Well, there should be two nested try/finally blocks

Comment: Once again, debug this. Step through the code, and at each line inspect the values. When you reach the line that fails, is `imgBanned` assigned? Is `imgBanned.Bitmap` assigned? Use break points, step through, and inspect values. These are crucial techniques that you need to master such that they are second nature.

Comment: Ok so it looks like imgBanned is assigned bit it doesnt get a bitmap: https://i.imgur.com/iKsIK1q.png

So if I'm correct it is trying to load an image that is not there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your own bitmap and then set TImageListItem.Bitmap to reference it in order to load images programmatically.

Check the documentation on TListViewItem.Bitmap property on how to handle this properly
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.ListView.Appearances.TListViewItem.Bitmap